# Styling item in drawer not reflecting in react native?

Tags: react-native, hybrid-mobile-app, native-base

I have been designing a drawer. When I tried to give some space between icon and text and also another icon it's not reflecting in output.

Whenever I'm changing or adding the styling it is not reflecting in the app, also I just need equal space between all texts and icons. Any help would be appreciated.

```js
import React, {Component} from "react";
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {ImageBackground, Platform, StyleSheet, BackHandler,View, TouchableHighlight} from "react-native";
// import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import {
    Container,
    Header,
    Body,
    Title,
    Left,
    Right,
    Content,
    Button,
    Text,
    Card,
    Form,
    Item,
    Input,
    Label,
    Icon,
    Toast,
    Separator,
    List,
    ListItem
} from 'native-base';
import FastImage from 'react-native-fast-image';
import { Col, Row, Grid } from 'react-native-easy-grid';
// import { Col, Row, Grid } from "react-native-easy-grid"; import AppNavigator
// from './navigation/AppNavigator'; const splash =
// require("./assets/images/splash.png ");
import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';
const redirectToMembers = () =>{
    Actions.members()
 }
 const routes = ["Home", "Chat", "Profile"];

// Activity subMenu 
 const ActivityMenu = (<View>
    <ListItem>
        <TouchableHighlight>
         <Text>Sent me a Smile</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
    </ListItem>
    <ListItem>
        <TouchableHighlight>
         <Text>Chat Received</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
    </ListItem>
    <ListItem>
        <TouchableHighlight>
         <Text>Added me to Favorites</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
    </ListItem>
    <ListItem>
        <TouchableHighlight>
         <Text>Viewd my Profile</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
    </ListItem>
    <ListItem>
        <TouchableHighlight>
         <Text>Notifications Sent</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
    </ListItem>
    <ListItem>
        <TouchableHighlight>
         <Text>Sent a Smile to them</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
    </ListItem>
    <ListItem>
        <TouchableHighlight>
         <Text>Chat Sent</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
    </ListItem>
  </View>)
//   end

// Search Sub Menu
const SearchMenu = (<View>
    <ListItem>
        <TouchableHighlight>
         <Text>Active Members</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
    </ListItem>
    <ListItem>
        <TouchableHighlight>
         <Text>Advanced Searches</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
    </ListItem>
    <ListItem>
        <TouchableHighlight>
         <Text>Basic Searches</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
    </ListItem>
    <ListItem>
        <TouchableHighlight>
         <Text>Horoscope Searches</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
    </ListItem>
  </View>)
// end

class SidebarScreen extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { activityItem: false, searchItem: false};
      }

    _logout = () => {
        // AsyncStorage.removeItem('userToken');
        // let userToken = {};
        // this.props.login(userToken);
        // Actions.login();
        BackHandler.exitApp();
    }

    
    render() {
        return (
            <Container>
                <View style={{ backgroundColor: '#AC1319', height: 40 }}>
                    <Grid>
                        <Col>
                        </Col>
                        <Col size={4}>
                            <FastImage
                                style={{
                                    width: '100%',
                                    height: 42,
                                }}
                                grounded
                                source={require('../assets/images/logo2.png')}
                                resizeMode={FastImage.resizeMode.contain} />
                        </Col>
                        <Col>
                        </Col>
                    </Grid>
                </View>
                <View style={{flex:1}}>

            <List>
                        <ListItem>
                            <TouchableHighlight  onPress={() => Actions.upload({redirectToMembers})}>
                               <Text>
                                 <Icon name='home' style={styles.leftIcon} />
                                 Home
                               </Text> 
                            </TouchableHighlight>
                        </ListItem>
                        <ListItem>
                            <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => Actions.results({
                                resultType:'favorites'
                            })}>
                             <Text>
                                <Icon name='message1' type="AntDesign" style={styles.leftIcon} />
                                Message
                             </Text>
                            </TouchableHighlight>
                        </ListItem>
                        <ListItem>
                            <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.setState({ activityItem: !this.state.activityItem })}>
                             <Text>
                                <Icon name='clockcircleo' type="AntDesign" style={styles.leftIcon} />
                                Activity
                                <Icon name={this.state.searchItem?"up":"down"} type="AntDesign" style={styles.RightIcon}/>
                             </Text>
                            </TouchableHighlight>
                        </ListItem>
                        {this.state.activityItem ? ActivityMenu : null}
                        <ListItem>
                            <TouchableHighlight>
                               <Text> 
                                   <Icon name='search' type="FontAwesome" style={styles.leftIcon}/>
                                  Search
                                  </Text>
                                
                            </TouchableHighlight>
                        </ListItem>
                       
                        <ListItem>
                            <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.setState({ searchItem: !this.state.searchItem })}>
                             <Text>
                                <Icon name='search-plus' type="FontAwesome" style={styles.leftIcon}/>
                                Popular Searches
                                <Icon name={this.state.searchItem?"up":"down"} type="AntDesign" style={styles.RightIcon}/>
                            </Text>
                            </TouchableHighlight>
                        </ListItem>
                        {this.state.searchItem ? SearchMenu : null}
                        <ListItem>
                            <TouchableHighlight>
                             <Text>
                                <Icon name='profile' type="AntDesign" style={styles.leftIcon}/>
                                My Profile
                             </Text>
                            </TouchableHighlight>
                        </ListItem>
                        <ListItem>
                            <TouchableHighlight>
                              <Text>
                                <Icon name='setting' type="AntDesign" style={styles.leftIcon} />
                                Setting
                              </Text>
                            </TouchableHighlight>
                        </ListItem>
                        <ListItem>
                            <TouchableHighlight>
                             <Text>
                                <Icon name='infocirlceo' type="AntDesign" style={styles.leftIcon}/>
                                Help
                             </Text>  
                            </TouchableHighlight>
                        </ListItem>
                        <ListItem>
                            <TouchableHighlight>
                             <Text>
                                <Icon name='file1' type="AntDesign" style={styles.leftIcon}/>
                                Other Pages !
                             </Text> 
                            </TouchableHighlight>
                        </ListItem>
                        <ListItem>
                            <TouchableHighlight>
                             <Text>
                               <Icon name='globe' type="FontAwesome" style={styles.leftIcon}/>
                                Join Our Partner Sites
                             </Text>
                            </TouchableHighlight>
                        </ListItem>
                        
                        <ListItem last>
                            <TouchableHighlight Primary onPress={() => this._logout()}>
                                <Text><Icon name='close' /> CLOSE APP</Text>
                            </TouchableHighlight>
                        </ListItem>

                
          </List>

                <View style={{position:"absolute",bottom:0,left:0,width:'100%'}}>
                    <Button block large Primary style={{width:'100%'}}><Text>Upgrade!</Text></Button>
                </View>

                </View>
            </Container>
        )
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center'
      },
    row: {
      flex: 1,
      justifyContent: "space-around"
    },
    button: {
      backgroundColor: 'blue',
      marginBottom: 10
    },
    text: {
      color: 'white',
      fontSize: 20,
      paddingLeft:20,
      paddingRight:20
    },
    leftIcon:{
        size:20,
        paddingLeft:20,
        paddingRight:40
    },
    RightIcon:{
        size:20,
        paddingLeft:40
    }
  });

  const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    user: state.user,
  });
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
      login:  (user) => dispatch({ type: 'LOGIN',user:user }),
      logout: () => dispatch({ type: 'LOGOUT' })
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(SidebarScreen);
```

[O/p](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCp9u.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. As written you have several separate questions (changing styling, equal spacing, icon not appearing). You are likely to get better answers if you edit your post to focus on only a single question with a [mcve].

Comment: Actually the main question is the margin and spacing i have given in the code in stylesheet should reflect but it is not reflecting so i want ot know the possible cause